# Change visibility of a component and scroll to it not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that has several components inside it:

```
<div  class="mx-sm-auto mb-5 px-0 container">
  <app-set-vehicle-details id="step1" #step1 (step1Finished)="enableStep2()"></app-set-vehicle-details>
  <app-product-selection id="step2" *ngIf="step2Enabled"></app-product-selection>
  <app-product-additional id="step3" *ngIf="step3Enabled"></app-product-additional>
</div>
```

All the child elements emmit a `finished` once they get unlocked and you can proceed to next step. So you enable the next step as follows:

```
step2Enabled = false;

enableStep2() {
  this.step2Enabled = true;
  this.scrollToElement('step2');
}

scrollToElement(id: string): void {
  const element = document.querySelector('#' + id);
  if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
  }
}
```

So `step2` component gets visible, but scroll to it it's not working. 
I assume this is happening because the visibility of the second component didn't to true before the `scrollToElement` call, because it works once the component is visible.

How can I make this behavior to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You're scrolling to something which doesn't yet exist. It will only exist on the next render.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was suspecting. How can I achieve that behavior? (That's my real question indeed...)

Comment: The easiest way would be to toggle `display: none` css style instead of `*ngIf`ing those elements.

Comment: Not working neither...

Comment: I solved it adding a delay of 50 ms....

Comment: It probably works also with a delay of 0 ms. An alternative is to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` before `scrollToElement`.

Comment: Actually it's still not working. It should be a ngIf, as the components are crashing if they don't have the needed information. Just changing `display` or `visibility` doesn't prevent the Component to try to fill all the needed information. So I have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the presence of the child component with `ViewChildren`, by subscribing to the `QueryList.changes` event.

First, set a template reference variable on the child component:

```
<app-product-selection #step2 *ngIf="step2Enabled"></app-product-selection>
```

Then use that variable to refer to the component host element in code, and subscribe to the `QueryList.changes` event in `ngAfterViewInit`. When the event is triggered, scroll the component into view:

```
@ViewChildren("step2", { read: ElementRef }) step2List: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.step2List.changes.subscribe(() => {
    if (this.step2List.length > 0) {
      (this.step2List.first.nativeElement as HTMLElement).scrollIntoView();
    }
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-36dejb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this:

```
enableStep2() {
   this.step2Enabled = true;
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.scrollToElement('step2');
   });
}
```

This waits until step2 is visible. So perfect!